# GCC ARM register expected

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm, inline-assembly

I'm trying to port [bunny](https://code.google.com/p/bunny-the-fuzzer/) to armv7h, which uses some x86 asm stuff that I'm having trouble converting to asm.

```
static __inline__ void atomic_inc(volatile int* ptr){
    __asm__ __volatile__("lock incl %0": "=m" (*ptr): "m" (*ptr));
}    

static __inline__ void atomic_dec(volatile int* ptr){
    __asm__ __volatile__("lock decl %0": "=m" (*ptr): "m" (*ptr));
}
```

Is what's there, I've tried

```
"ADD/SUB %0 %0": "=r" (*ptr): "m" (*ptr));
```

And both give

```
Error: ARM register expected -- `add [r3] [r3]'
```

and

```
Error: ARM register expected -- `sub [r4] [r4]'
```

Compiled using:

```
armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -Wall -O3 -funroll-loops -fno-strict-aliasing
-ffast-math -Wno-pointer-sign -mcpu=cortex-a15 -mfpu=neon -marm
```

Comment: "m" is the wrong constraint, for a start (it should be "0", I think - I hate how confusing GCC's extended asm is). More generally, that's not going to be atomic. A simple search of an ARM reference manual or on here will tell you how to implement atomics with `LDREX`/`STREX`.

Comment: @Notlikethat Trying that gives "warning matching constraint does not allow a register" and still errors.

Answer (score 3):

The clue lies in the error message - which is entirely accurate.

ARM arithmetic instructions take three [operands](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.qrc0001l/QRC0001_UAL.pdf):

`ADD{S} rd, rs, <operand>`

`SUB{S} rd, rs, <operand>`

Where `operand` is one of:

- A register
- An immediate value
- A register shifted by a constant
- A register shifted by another register

in your case, I imagine you would want an immediate constant of `1`, which would give an assembler instruction of

`ADD rd, rd, #1`

However, this misses the fundamental flaw that you are trying to implement an atomic increment of a *memory location*.  The compiler is generating a load from memory instruction in order to implement the dereference of `ptr`. It's not immediately obvious it ever generates a stores of the result.  Even if it did, this would be at best, a non-atomic sequence of 3 instructions (load, increment, store).

I would recommend looking at [GCC's atomic intrinsics](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) rather than rolling your own.

Comment: I wasn't rolling my own, it's what was in the source already. I'm not very familiar with ARM asm, as should be obvious. How would `ADD rd, rd, #1` translate to inline asm?

Comment: @user3696583 Asking about asm means you are rolling your own. Why not use `__sync_fetch_and_add(ptr,1)`, which will work just as well on x86 and arm?

Comment: If that's the case, the implementation is fundamentally broken and offers none of the thread-safety benefits that are expected for callers of these functions. 

The easiest way of implementing this function is with C++11's `std::atomic` - which provides a truly atomic `++` operator.  It's also possible with C11's  `atomic_compare_exchange_weak` in a loop, but this requires a bit more effort.

Comment: @user3696583 I'm with @Marc Glisse on this one. Correctly implementing atomic operations in assembler is hard - particularly getting memory barriers in the right place.  Typically implementations need to use a spin-lock and `LDREX and STREX` instructions. 

Seeing as you've just asked a really elementary question on ARM assembler and have failed to spot the glaring problem with the existing approach, your chances of  hand-rolling this in assembler are slim.  Use a known working implementation, preferring those from C11 or C++11 over GCC's intrinsics simply for reasons of portability.